# Select data between night and day hours

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp, time-series

My data looks like this, it is a **minute based** data for 2 years.

1. 2017-04-02 00:00:00
2. 2017-04-02 00:01:00
3. 2017-04-02 00:02:00
4. 2017-04-02 00:03:00
5. 2017-04-02 00:04:00
6. ....
7. 2017-04-02 23:59:00
8. ...
9. 2019-02-01 22:54:00
10. 2019-02-01 22:55:00
11. 2019-02-01 22:56:00
12. 2019-02-01 22:57:00
13. 2019-02-01 22:58:00
14. 2019-02-01 22:59:00
15. 2019-02-01 23:00:00

I want to access all the data rows between the end of the workday to the beginning of the next. Example between **2018-04-02 18:00:00 2018-04-03 05:00:00** for all the days in my data frame. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `DatetimeIndex` then you can use `.between_time`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2017-04-02', freq='90min', periods=100)})
df = df.set_index('date')

df.between_time('18:00', '5:00')

#date
#2017-04-02 00:00:00
#2017-04-02 01:30:00
#2017-04-02 03:00:00
#2017-04-02 04:30:00
#2017-04-02 18:00:00
#2017-04-02 19:30:00
#2017-04-02 21:00:00
#2017-04-02 22:30:00
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is boolean indexing based on conditions on the datetime column or index. Assuming your DataFrame is named `df` and it has a DatetimeIndex equal to the example data you've posted, try this:

```
df[(df.index.hour >= 18) | (df.index.hour <= 5)]
```

Comment: Shouldnt this be `&` instead of `|`?

Comment: @Erfan, I think it should be `|`: `df.index.hour` takes on integer values between 0 and 23 inclusive, and we're interested in keeping the row if that integer is either <= 5 or >= 18.